# Geolocation of android device

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

How can I get **continuous** geo-location of android device programmatically ?

I'm having troubles of getting position coordinates continuously of android device and show the navigation move according to the geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android documentation :

> // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
>   this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
>
> // Define a listener that responds to location updates
>   LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
>       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
>         // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
>         makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
>       }
>
> ```
> public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
>
> public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
>
> public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}   };
> ```
>
> // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location
>   updates

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
> 0, 0, locationListener);
```

More information available on their page : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: ya it the marker movement is working but the move is not smooth. how to make movement smoothly?